# Unable to find the React configuration template in WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I am starting a new project with WebStorm and I cannot find the template configuration for running React in the list of templates. Where I have seen examples select it above the one for React Native it does not exist for me.

[image]

Please advice where I should be looking I have already searched for the answer and updated my IDE. I can use `npm start` but I need hot reloading for development really.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any special templates for this
Please refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.2/react.html#react_running_and_debugging for the instructions on running/debugging React applications.

You need using a [Javascript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.2/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration for debugging the front-end apps that run in browser and [NPM](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.2/run-debug-configuration-npm.html) run configuration to start NPM scripts. For React apps, the IDE normally auto-creates the required run configurations as described in the *Help* article mentioned above. All you need is starting the app and then using the auto-created run configuration to attach a debugger to it

Comment: its not hot reloading though?

Comment: React hot reloading is done on the server end, it's not the IDE functionality. If the app is not re-built and reloaded when you save files with *File > Save All*, check if disabling *Back up files before saving* in *Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings* makes any difference. If it doesn't, please report an issue to https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues; see also https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9904 and https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6255 for some hints